# How to grep and show only the data I want from the output of a running program?

Tags: linux, shell

I know by running

```
./mycommand | grep "keywords"
```

will get me the line of the `keywords` located after the program has finished executing.

But what if my program is running/looping constantly for a long time and logs out the results after each loop, how can I grep once a new output appears in the terminal without having the need to wait it finish executing?

Comment: `keywords located after the program has finished executing.` No. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: Thanks for the info, I tested it last time but it did not work, not sure why, maybe i entered the wrong keyword

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, the best is to log the results of `mycommand` to a logfile, something like `/var/log/mycommand_logfile.log` (your program `mycommand` might need to be modified in order to do so).

You then open a new terminal and launch the following command:

```
tail -f /var/log/mycommand_logfile.log | grep "keywords"
```

This will show the last lines, while they get written during `mycommand`'s execution.

Comment: If to be picky, `tail -f` doesn't seem to end automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're saying, what you have *should* be doing what you want. Grep doesn't wait for its input to end. It processes it line by line and produces output whenever it encounters a line that matches what it's looking for.

If you're finding that it's not working this way, is there anything else in your command line that might be producing the blockage? Like, for example, if you're really doing something like:

```
./mycommand | sort | grep "keyword"
```

then the "sort" command will wait until it's gotten all the data so it can sort it before passing it on to grep.

Or perhaps the problem is that mycommand is a very resource-intensive operation, and running at a high priority, so that grep doesn't get any cpu cycles until mycommand isn't running any more. I'm just spitballing here. The point is, you're doing the command line right.